# Как редактировать шаблон уведомлений wordpress?(не woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример сообщения который приходит. Нужно добавить переводы строк и удалить лишние ссылки по типу одобрить в спам и прочее.

Возможно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать через [фильтр](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_moderation_text/) `comment_moderation_text`

Сама функция,отвечающая за отправку  `wp_notify_moderator`

Но там и так добавлены переходы на новую строку,в конце каждого предложения. Странно что у вас их нет.

Answer (score 0):

Кому нужно будет можно полностью переписать функцию

```html
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Замена базовой функции wp_notify_moderator()
*/

if ( !function_exists('wp_notify_moderator') ){
 function wp_notify_moderator($comment_id) {
  // здесь код функции, можно скопировать базовый код и изменить под свои нужды
 }
}
?>
```